# Prove $\int_Rfg\,dm\leq\|f\|_p^{1-p/r}\|g\|_p^{1-q/r}(\int_Rf^pg^q\,dm)^{1/r}$, where $1\leq p\leq\infty$ and $\frac1{r}=\frac1{p}+\frac1{q}-1$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, holder-inequality

Let $f$, $g$ be positive real functions. And $f \in L^p(R)$, $g \in L^q(R)$, and $1 \leqslant p,q <\infty$. Then $fg \in L^1(R)$ and 
$$ \int_R fg \,dm\;\leqslant\; \|f\|_p^{1-p/r}\|g\|_p^{1-q/r}\left(\int_R f^pg^q \,dm\right)^{1/r}$$
Where
$$1\leqslant p \leqslant +\infty \quad\text{and}\quad\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}-1$$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the norm for $g$ be $q$? While you're correcting that, why not add some context? I have an answer, but unless there is more context, it would not be right to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: I suppose $1+\frac 1 r =\frac 1 p +\frac 1 q$. Write $fg$ as $f^{p/r}g^{q/r} f^{1-p/r}g^{1-q/r}$ and apply Holder with conjugate indices $r$  and $\frac r {r-1}$. You will get $(\int f^{p}g^{q})^{1/r}$ as one of the factors. Now applying another Holder to complete the proof is fairly straightfoward.

Comment: Actually, the condition *is* $\frac1r=\frac1p+\frac1q-1$.